# In Shadowbox scrolling not working in any apple device

Tags: ipad, safari, scroll, ipod, shadowbox

I am using `shadowbox` to display content in a pop-up window. When the content is longer than the screen size, scrolling appears in all PCs and Android device but it does not appear on any Apple devices (Iphone, Ipad, Ipod)

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit of a late reply but I have just had the same problem and I though I would share my solution just in case it was helpful.

I created a scrollable div using css
overflow-y: scroll;
within the shadowbox frame and this enabled the content to be scrollable on the ipad.

Answer (score 0):

Try this so it doesn't create double scroll bars on other devices target the iDevice.

```
    $(window).load(function(){

            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) {

                $('#sb-body-inner').css({
                    'overflow': 'scroll', 
                    '-webkit-overflow-scrolling': 'touch' 
                }); 

            }
    });
```